# multiprocessing.Process subclass using shared queue

Tags: python

I'm using the `multiprocessing` module on Python 2.7 on Windows and I have multiple processes putting data on and taking data off of shared queues. I'm subclassing `multiprocessing.Process` to do this, and passing in queue proxies made by a `multiprocessing.Manager()` as arguments to `__init__`. In other answers on SO I've seen people pass this queue proxy into `map_async` as an argument, but when I try to give it as an argument to the `__init__` method I get the error:

```
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
```

So I understand that on Windows things you pass to instantiate `Process` subclasses have to be pickle-able, and that there needs to be an authkey on these shared objects (which prevents pickling). But why can you give that queue proxy to `map_async` and not a `Process` subclass? Is there any good way around this besides rewriting my `Process` subclasses as functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map_async` isn't equivalent to initializing/running a `Process` with the given arguments, `apply_async` is.  `map_async` takes an iterable, in your example a `Manager.Queue`, splits it up in to batches (effectively unpacking/repacking it in to a series of tuples), then starts the workers and hands off the batches, not the original iterable.  `apply_async`, or just starting the process directly, actually passes the exact object you provide in to the workers as one of their arguments.  You also happen to be using a proxy `Queue` from the `Manager`, and all proxies produced by `Manager`s have an `AuthenticationString` member attached to them, which, as your error states, is unpicklable for security reasons, so can't be propagated down to the workers.

Is there a reason you are using a `Manager` to produce your `Queue`?  Unless you are using it over a network or something, you should be just fine using a standard `multiprocessing.Queue`, which won't have the picklability issue (since that derives from being a `Manager` proxy).

Incidentally, at least from my reading of the code, it looks like using a `Manager.Queue`, or even a regular old `multiprocessing.Queue` or `Queue` as an input to `map_async` is fairly pointless, as the iterable being mapped is completely consumed in the parent process before any workers are even created, then never looked at again.

Comment: So I was originally using this code on Linux and had no issues using a `multiprocessing.Queue`. When I ran this code on Windows, it gave me an error stating that queues should only be shared through inheritance, so I thought that I would be able to share the queue proxy (apparently not). It's not clear to me exactly how exactly I would inherit from the queue - how would each `Process` instance share?

Comment: You answered basically what I was asking, just curious at this point.

Comment: Actually, looking over the example of using a `Manager` from the docs directly, I'm not 100% clear on how that example works either.  When I've used `multiprocess.Queue` before (on Windows), I just provided it in `args` when creating the `Process`.  What was the error you got specifically?

Comment: `RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`
I am actually getting this while making a `pickle.dumps` call (just used to debug because I was getting rather cryptic EOFErrors before and I suspected that the error had to do with pickling.

Comment: So this is kind of obvious once you've seen it, but not intuitive beforehand.  `Pool` creats it's own worker `Process`es, then actually pushes the worker functions on to the work queue as arguments.  That means that your entire process object and queue has to be pickled/unpickled for every task run.  If you want to use a custom `Process` subclass instead of writing your worker as a function, it looks like you'll also have to subclass `Pool` to create and run instances of your subclass.