# Python, Multiprocessing and GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, gtk3, pygobject

I have a program with a GUI that needs to do some multiprocessing. The point of it is to avoid freezing the GUI, and to allow the user using some other buttons while the process is running.

I'd like then to define a method like the following:

```
def start_waiting(self, parent, func, args):

    self.window_waiting.show()

    task=Process(func(*args))
    task.start()

    task.join()

    # Some code to execute at the end of the process
    #
    #...
```

The problem is that `join()` is not working, and I need it because the code executed after `join()` indicates when the `Process` has ended. I'll use that code to update a cancel button of the `window_waiting`.

I then came in mind with another solution to avoid using`join()`, I replaced it with:

```
while task.is_alive():
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

But it didn't worked neither, so I tried a plan C, which was to create a queue:

```
def worker(input, output):
    for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        result=func(*args)
        output.put(result)


task_queue = Queue()
done_queue = Queue()
task_queue.put(task)

Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()
done_queue.get()
```

The last code gave me the error: `'Pickling an AuthenticationString object is '
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons`

Which lead me to [multiprocessing.Process subclass using shared queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578844/multiprocessing-process-subclass-using-shared-queue) but I haven't managed to solve the problem :/

Comment: `The problem is that the join() function is not working` How?

Comment: @Colonel The code that is after the function join() it is executed before `task` finish

Comment: ( I tough that this was understood because that is the roll of the join() function )

Comment: It never hurts to be specific. It could also be throwing an error, or something else.

Comment: @Colonel Yep, you're right :)

Comment: @rsm what does `func` look like? What does it return?

Comment: @dano To be honest i don't know. I adapted a script that I've been using to create multiprocessing queues with multiples number of process. I got the main script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797998/is-it-possible-to-multiprocesspython-a-function-that-returns-something) i can't give a direct link. It is the answer given by cha0site.

Comment: @rsm I'm confused. In your first example, you have a `start_waiting` function that you pass a `func` argument to. Then you do this: ` task=Process(func(*args))`, which calls `func(*args)` in the *parent* process, then passes its return value to `Process`. Is that really what you're trying to do?

Comment: @dano No i don't think that i want to do that, i dont really care about the return value, i just want to multiprocess the func. I created `task=Process(func(args))` in order to start a process (detached from its parent). This is because `start_waiting` it is a GUI with a terminal and i need to execute different kinds of commands in the terminal, so instead of creating multiple functions, i created 1 GUI function that executes X terminal function. I hope be clear enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example should look like this:

```
def start_waiting(self,parent,func,args):

    ...not relevant code..

    self.window_waiting.show()


    task=Process(target=func, args=args)  # This line is different.
    task.start()


    task.join()
```

The way you had it, it wasn't actually executing `func` in a child process; it was executing it in the parent, and then passing the return value to `Process`. When you called `task.start()`, it would probably instantly fail, because you were passing it whatever `func` returned, rather than a function object.

Note that because you're calling `task.join()` inside `start_waiting`, it's probably going to block your GUI, because `start_waiting` won't return until `func` completes, even though its running in a child process. The only way it wouldn't block is if you're running `start_waiting` in a separate thread from the GUI's event loop. You probably want something more like this:

```
def start_waiting(self,parent,func,args):

    ...not relevant code..

    self.window_waiting.show() # You should interact with the GUI in the main thread only.

    self.task = Process(target=func, args=args)  # This line is different.
    self.thrd = threading.Thread(target=self.start_and_wait_for_task)
    self.thrd.start()


def start_and_wait_for_task(self):
    """ This runs in its own thread, so it won't block the GUI. """
    self.task.start()
    self.task.join()
    # If you need to update the GUI at all here, use GLib.idle_add (see https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading)
    # This is required to safely update the GUI from outside the main thread.
```

Comment: I just tried changing `task=Process(target=func, args=args)` but i get the same result :/, thanks for the note, that explains me a problem that i had before. I still don't really knowing how should i realize this GUI/Multiprocessing. Would it be possible that you take a look to my program? I just started programing and this has been really difficult to solve >.<

Comment: "in a separate thread" I tend to confuse threads and process, i'm gona take a good look in to that. I've tried everything except using threads!

Comment: @rsm What is going on in `func`? Are you sure that it isn't failing or ending sooner than you expect for some reason? I've used `multiprocessing.Process` many times, and `join` has always worked exactly like its supposed to.

Comment: the first time it didn't work (i dont know why, it should have worked as you said, blocking the GUI). Instead i created two functions as you adviced, and i created a third function `change_button` that has the code of ` ... the code that should be executed only when task ended...` and i added `GLib.idle_add(change_button)` after join() and it works perfectly!!

Comment: @rsm Cool! Also, I rolled back your edit, because I really meant to make the `threading.Thread` object use a different instance variable than `self.task`. But I did forget to actually call `start()` on the thread object, which your edit made me realize. So, thanks!

Comment: it is funny that after you rolled back my edit my program ain't working anymore haha (but i'm sure that it must be my mistake). Anyways you gave me a lot of useful information to work with. BY long time i tried to do some "hacks" in order to update the GUI from child process

Comment: @rsm You definitely don't want to try to update the GUI from the child process! Doing it from a separate thread is ok, as long as you use `GLib.idle_add`

Comment: i can confirm now that the solution works pretty good. The problem was coming from my program. The commands of my program are sent to a VTE terminal, so join() was detecting when the commands was being send to the VTE instead of when they was actually finishing!